# "who has been much reviled"

Tags: quantifiers

> A man like [Andrew] Lloyd Webber who has been **much** reviled for his conservative politics ... [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/culture/2016/apr/26/ben-elton-on-arts-funding-put-the-money-into-grassroots-the-high-end-will-look-after-itself)

Can we replace it with *a lot of*?

Also it will be great if you could describe the below:

What is part of speech of *much*? and What is the function (Clause Element) of this word in the sentence?

Comment: Here [link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/much_1?q=much).

Comment: Short answer: no, because **a lot of** only goes with nouns, and *reviled* is a participle.  I'm looking for a good reference for the grammar, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: I think it's adverb here, it is described the participle "revield".  but I'm not sure

Comment: You can say "been reviled a lot for", but not "a lot *of*", which as @stangdon said applies to nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stangdon points out, in this sentence "reviled" is a participle and requires the adverb "much".  If you change the sentence to use a similar noun, then it would be possible to use either:

> ... Andrew Lloyd Webber who has received (much / a lot of) [vilification](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vilification) for his conservative politics, ...